# Updating swiftmailer from 4.1.3 to 5.4.9 caused attachments to be encoded in body

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Kayako Help Desk always gave an error when trying to send foreign chars in the name or subject and it was coming from swiftmailer.  I decided to update swiftmailer to see if would fix.  Things are working (I needed to do some renaming as they used SwiftMailer_ instead of Swift_ so renamed the swiftmailer part to use SwiftMailer instead of Swift because they already had a Swift class).   Anyway, while things are working, the problem is the email sent when it has attachments comes in encoded and outlook 2010 cannot see the attachment it's all the raw base64 encoding in the body.   Why is it doing that (what do I need to change?)?  Thanks!!  Here's my sample message (modified to change domain, etc):

```
Return-Path: <support@example.com>
Delivered-To: my-mydomain:com-common@example.com
X-Envelope-To: common@example.com
Received: (qmail 75685 invoked by uid 3002); 24 Mar 2018 16:21:24 -0000
Delivered-To: my-mydomain:com-test@example.com
Received: (qmail 75678 invoked from network); 24 Mar 2018 16:21:24 -0000
Received: from localhost (HELO server1.hosting.com) (127.0.0.1)
  by localhost with ESMTPS (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX encrypted); 24 Mar 2018 16:21:24 -0000
Received: by server1.hosting.com (Postfix, from userid 3002)
    id XXXXXXXXXX; Sat, 24 Mar 2018 12:21:24 -0400 (EDT)
To: test@example.com
Subject: [!JIJ-378-38213]: test attachments with new mail
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 3002:SimpleMailInvoker.php
Message-ID: <85813f39edb1fe7703129c308631f652@swift.generated>
Date: Sat, 24 Mar 2018 09:21:24 -0700
From: "Joe Tester." <support@example.com>
Reply-To: support@example.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="=?utf-8?Q?=5F=3D=5Fswiftmailer=5Fv4=5F1521908484=5Fe2a5856ffdce83f648b?=
 =?utf-8?Q?424876afd452c=5F=3D=5F?="
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)


--_=_swiftmailer_v4_1521908484_e2a5856ffdce83f648b424876afd452c_=_
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<font face=3D"Verdana, Arial, Helvetica" size=3D"2">test attachments wit=
h new mail<br />
------------------------------<br />
<br />
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Ticket ID: JIJ-378-38213</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">URL: <a href=3D"https://www.mydom=
ain.com/kayako/staff/index.php?/Tickets/Ticket/View/31771">https://=
www.example.com/kayako/staff/index.php?/Tickets/Ticket/View/=
31771</a></div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Full Name: Joe Tester.</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Email: <a href=3D"mailto:joetest@myd=
main.com">joetest@example.com</a></div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Creator: User</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Department: Support</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Staff (Owner): -- Unassigned --</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Type: Issue</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Status: Open</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Priority: Normal</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">SLA: Default 12 Hours Plan</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Template Group: Default</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Created: 24 March 2018 09:21 AM</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Updated: 24 March 2018 09:21 AM</div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Due: 26 March 2018 12:00 PM (2d 2h 39m)</=
div>
<div style=3D"margin-left: 40px;">Resolution Due: 28 March 2018 12:00 AM =
(3d 14h 39m)</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
Let's see what happens.<br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
<a href=3D"http://www.example.com" target=3D"_blank">http://www.=
example.com</a><br />
<br />
 <br />
<br />
<br />

<br />
<HR style=3D"margin-bottom: 6px; height: 1px; BORDER: none; color: #cfcf=
cf; background-color: #cfcfcf;" />
Staff CP:  <a href=3D"https://www.example.com/kayako/staff" tar=
get=3D"_blank">https://www.example.com/kayako/staff</a><br />
</font>

--_=_swiftmailer_v4_1521908484_e2a5856ffdce83f648b424876afd452c_=_
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=testpicxx.gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testpicxx.gif
SNIPPED ALL THIS!
FAABCcAADeABK9ADQuAEWkAGcYAIoVALzYAOEPUlAQEAOw==

--_=_swiftmailer_v4_1521908484_e2a5856ffdce83f648b424876afd452c_=_--
```

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the header, I figured it had to be something with all the nonsense going on in the `boundary=` line so in `swiftmailer/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php` I changed:

`$this->_boundary = '_=_swiftmailer_v4_'.time().'_'.md5(getmypid().mt_rand().uniqid('', true)).'_=_';`

to

`$this->_boundary = 'swiftmailerv4'.time().'x'.md5(getmypid().mt_rand().uniqid('', true));`

and now things are working.

But since it appears to be messing up header fields that aren't supported by email clients, I wonder if I'm going to run in to any problems if subject or to/from/cc have characters needing encoding?   I can't use the V6 of swiftmailer because kayako doesn't support php7.